# delete rows with apply

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I have a `data.frame` and wish to delete rows that match certain somewhat complex criteria.  I can do so using a repetitive series of lines as below.  However, this approach is not general.

```
my.df <- read.table(text = '
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9
    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0
    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1
    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1
    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0
    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1
    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1
    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1
    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0
    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0
', header = TRUE)

desired.result <- read.table(text = '
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1
    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
', header = TRUE)

# this works, but is not general

my.df2 <- my.df
my.df2 <- my.df2[!(my.df2[,1]==0 & (my.df2[,4]==1 | my.df2[,5]==1)),]
my.df2 <- my.df2[!(my.df2[,2]==0 & (my.df2[,6]==1 | my.df2[,7]==1)),]
my.df2 <- my.df2[!(my.df2[,3]==0 & (my.df2[,8]==1 | my.df2[,9]==1)),]
my.df2

row.names(my.df2) <- NULL
all.equal(my.df2, desired.result)
# [1] TRUE
```

I would like to generalize this code.  I regularly combine `sapply` and `apply` to operate on data.  However, I guess I have never combined those function to delete data and I cannot figure out how to do it.

The code below identifies which lines to delete, but does not delete them.  Numerous variations of the code below have not worked.

```
my.df3 <- as.matrix(my.df)

sapply(seq_along(1:3), function(i) {
       apply(my.df3, 1, function(j) { 
            !(j[i]==0 & (j[(i+1)*2]==1 | j[((i+1)*2+1)]==1)) 
       }) 
})
```

I could find no solution searching the internet for 'delete rows with apply'.  Thank you for any advice.  I prefer a solution in base `R`.  I suspect a simple modification of the `sapply` statement is all that is needed.  Although, perhaps an entirely different approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `seq_along(1:3)` is redundant as that function will simply return `1:3`. Second, if the result of your `apply(..., 1, ...)` call is a logical vector, you can simply subset using it:

```
my.df3[apply(my.df3, 1, ...,), ]
```

Comment: Please consider including functional code that returns the desired result.  I am having a little difficulty seeing how to apply your answer to the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional solution based on combining variations tried before posting with Robert Krzyzanowski's suggestion of nesting an `apply` within `my.df3`:

```
my.df3 <- as.matrix(my.df)

my.test <- sapply(seq_along(1:3), function(i) {
                  apply(my.df3, 1, function(j) { 
                       !(j[i]==0 & (j[(i+1)*2]==1 | j[((i+1)*2+1)]==1)) 
                  })
}) 

my.df3[apply(my.test,1,function(i) {all(i)==TRUE}),]

     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
```